# Electron Installer integrity check has failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron, nsis

I've build an Electron App with `electron-builder` tools for Windows plateform only, and the app work nice.

But, i've problem with specific usecase :

If i copy my .exe file on a USB key and i run this copy on other computer, i've this error :

`Installer integrity check has failed`

My app is not signed, do you think the problem can be this ?

If i download my .exe file with HTTP link, the install is ok. I've this message only if i copy the .exe on other support.

Thank you community !

[image]

Comment: You may want to use `target: "portable"` instead of `nsis`, that will allow your application to be run without installation [docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/win)

Comment: Yes, i think its my last option :D but idealy, i would like know why my file copy dont work :/

Comment: fix this poblem ? same too

Answer (score 3):

NSIS displays that message if the data in the .exe has changed.

Most likely you have a hardware problem, either with the USB key or the RAM on the problematic machine. It could also be a virus infection.

Try a different USB key or another machine.

You can [ignore the CRC check](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#installerusagecommon) by running `"c:\path\to\mysetup.exe" /NCRC` but I don't really recommend that because it might create a broken install or even crash.

Comment: Hi, i've try different USB and other machine, same problem :/